# How to differentiate constructing confidence intervals?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, standard-error

I am a bit confused when looking at the confidence interval formula for one of my class and I am looking to see if anyone can clarify it.

When constructing, let's say, a 95% confidence interval of a sample mean the formula is:

$\overline{Y} \displaystyle \pm 1.96 * SE$ where the $SE = \frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{N}}$. However, in some cases the $SE =\sqrt{\sigma^2} $. How can I differentiate between the two? Is it because $ \sqrt{\sigma^2_\overline{Y}} =  \frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2_x}}{\sqrt{N}}$?

Sorry if that sounds confusing but it's been giving me a bit trouble to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this might be longer than I care for it to be.  Go along with it because I think it will clarify some things".

Your estimate of the mean is actually a random variable.  That is because $\bar{Y}$ is a function of random variables (more specifically a scaled sum $\bar{Y} = \sum_i x_i/n$), and a function of random quantities is itself a random quantity.

It is completely sensible to ask "if $\bar{Y}$ is a random variable, then what is its distribution".  According to the central limit theorem, the asymptotic (that is, with enough data) sampling distribution of $\bar{Y}$ is

$$\bar{Y} \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\mu, \dfrac{\sigma^2_x}{N} \right)$$

Here $\mu$ is the true mean of the distribution that gave you the data $x_i$ and $\sigma^2_x$ is the variance of the distribution that gave you the data $x_i$.  $N$ is the size of the sample used to compute $\bar{Y}$.  We call the quantity $\sqrt{\sigma^2_x}/\sqrt{N} = \sigma_{\bar{Y}}$ the *standard error of the mean*.  The standard error is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution.

So when you use the CI formula, you are essentially telling people where the middle 95% probability exists for that sampling distribution.

So, to answer your question

- $\sigma_{\bar{Y}}$ is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution.  It is computed using...
- $\sigma_x$ which is the standard deviation of the data in your sample.